# Render nsimage offscreen and set pointer for decklink videoframe

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, cgimage, cgbitmapcontext

I'm developing on osx.

I'm trying to set a pointer to pixel data rendered offscreen from an nsimage object.
This is my code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSImage*)image
{
if (self = [super init])
{
    // set size
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, [image size].width, [image size].height);

    // set image
    frameImageRef = [image CGImageForProposedRect:NULL context:NULL hints:NULL];

    frameContextRef = CreateARGBBitmapContext(frameImageRef);

    CGContextDrawImage(frameContextRef, rect, frameImageRef);
}
return self;
}

- (int) getBytesPerRow
{
    return (int)CGImageGetBytesPerRow(frameImageRef);
}
```

With following code i pass set a pointer to my decklink frame

```
- (void*) renderToDeckLink;
{
    return CGBitmapContextGetData (frameContextRef);
}
```

Al objects are initializing fine. No errors, everything looks like the image is rendered into memory.

This is my code where i create a decklink frame for playback onto a decklink device:

```
- (void) createVideoFrame:(NSImage*)image
{
    // clear previous videoframe
    if (videoFrame != NULL)
    {
        videoFrame->Release();
    }
```

The code on top of this post is located at the renderFrame class

```
    // create renderFrame object
    renderFrame *frame = [[renderFrame alloc] initWithFrame:image];

    // get displaymode
    IDeckLinkDisplayMode* decklinkdisplaymode = (IDeckLinkDisplayMode*)CurrentRes;

    // create new videoframe on output
    if (deckLinkOutput->CreateVideoFrame((int)decklinkdisplaymode->GetWidth(), (int)decklinkdisplaymode->GetHeight(), [frame getBytesPerRow], bmdFormat8BitARGB, bmdFrameFlagDefault, &videoFrame) != S_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"error");
        // failed to create new video frame on output
    }
```

Following line of code is where i pass the pixeldata pointer to the videoframe object:

```
    // fill frame with buffer
    videoFrame->GetBytes((void**)[frame renderToDeckLink]);

    // schedule frame
    [self scheduleVideoFrame];

    // release pixeldata
   [frame releaseData];
}
```

Everything is compiling. Pixeldata is being rendered offscreen. The frames are correctly scheduled and playbacked on the decklink device. But all i get is a black screen. So maybe there's something wrong with the pointer to the pixeldata? I can't se where the fault is located.

Any help is more then welcome!

Thx
Thomas

Comment: What does this mean: "The frames are correctly scheduled and playbacked on the decklink device. But all i get is a black screen." Does it correctly play back or is the screen black? I don't understand.

Comment: I got a blackmagic decklink extreme 3D pci-e card. There's a sdk available for developing code for playout files to this cards. Workflow -> first create a new videoframe then fill it with pixel data (which is where i stuck) then pass it to the decklink device for scheduling and playback. This runs all without errors butt the frames are black. I think the pixeldata rendered in memory is not correctly passed to thr videoframe objects. But i can't see how.

Comment: so i think the pointer to the decklinkframe doesn't point to the right memory place. That's maybe why I get a black screen output (no pixel data -> gives black screen). But i don't know what's wrong.